# How to use DI container in reusable library?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm building a reusable library in PHP which will be used by multiple in-house applications (some web some not). I use constructor dependency injection mostly for my classes, for example injecting my Repository classes into business logic classes:

```
namespace \Company\Project\BusinessLogic;

class MyComplexBusinessWorkflow
{
    private $_repository;

    public function __construct(IMyEntityRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->_repository = $repository
    }

    ...
}
```

So with [Dice](https://r.je/dice.html) I'd like to have something like this which inject default for the library `IMyEntityRepository` implementation:

```
$my_complex_workflow_instance = $dice->create('MyComplexBusinessWorkflow');
```

instead of:

```
$my_complex_workflow_instance = new MyComplexBusinessWorkflow(new MyEntityMySQLRepository(new MysqlConnectionWrapper()));
```

I'm ok with embedding particular DI container library into my library code, but not sure how to manage container instance (`$dice` in the code above) itself.

Comment: Not really an answer but a little related: there is [container-interop](https://github.com/container-interop/container-interop) which provides a standard that some containers implement. That allows you to use a container without tying yourself to a specific implementation. Maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Looks very interesing, maybe you know about similar initiative in other languages?

Comment: Yes there are a couple of JSR that cover dependency injection (so Java here). Except that I don't know. We have been pushing container-interop in the PHP-FIG so that it becomes a PSR, still work in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't get an answer, so provide my "solution". I've implemented a separate Builder class for instantiating DI container.

Code that will use a library will have a dependency on the particular container, this can be absracted by an interface. Unfortunatelly different DI containers work in different way, so that's not a complete abstraction.

In comments I was pointed to this interesting initiative to unify DI containers in PHP: https://github.com/container-interop/container-interop